# Should you trust the ruling of the majority of rely on the most reliable?

Tags: probability, statistics

A signal flag has been hoisted over the next hill.  You cannot go to observe the color of the flag, but you have three associates who are fit, willing, and able to make the trip.  Unfortunately each of these guys is partially color-blind.  Al will correctly identify the color with probability 0.9, Bo will get it right with probability 0.8, and Ci will correctly identify the color of the flag with probability 0.7.  Should you send Al, your most reliable soldier, and accept his read, or should you send all three and trust the ruling of the majority?

Comment: Calculate the probability that a majority are wrong, and compare that with the probability that Al is wrong. Alternatively, calculate the probability that Al is right and they override him, and the probability that Al is wrong and they override him, and see which is bigger.

Comment: The first suggestion is more straightforward, though it requires more arithmetic. There are four ways for the majority to be wrong: A right and B and C wrong; B right and A and C wrong; C right and A and B wrong; and all three wrong. Calculate the probability of each; the sum of those four numbers is the probability that the majority is wrong. Now compare that with A’s probability of being wrong; which is smaller?

Comment: First, the probability that A is wrong is $0.1$, not $0.3$. More important, the probability that A is right and the other two are wrong is the *product* of three probabilities, *not* one of the numbers $0.1,0.2$, and $0.3$. Similarly, the product that all three are wrong is a *product* of three probabilities.

Comment: You’re getting closer, but you’re forgetting a factor in each of the first three terms: the probability that **A is right** and the other two are wrong is not $0.2\cdot0.3$, but rather $0.9\cdot0.2\cdot0.3$. If you recalculate those first three terms, you should find that it’s very close, but it’s slightly better to send all three.

Comment: (0.9*0.3*0.2) + (0.7*0.2*0.1) + (0.8*0.3*0.1) + (0.3*0.2*0.1) = 0.054 + 0.014 + 0.024 + .006 = 0.098 > 0.1 So send all 3 because they will be wrong slightly less often.

Comment: There you go; that looks good now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two fairly straightforward approaches. You can calculate the probability that a majority are wrong, and compare that with the probability that Al is wrong. Alternatively, you can calculate the probability that Al is right and they override him, and the probability that Al is wrong and they override him, and see which is bigger.

The first requires a little more arithmetic but is also a little more straightforward. There are four ways that the majority can be wrong:

- Al is right but the other two are wrong;
- Bo is right but the other two are wrong;
- Ci is right but the other two are wrong;
- all three are wrong.

These four events are mutually exclusive, so the probability that at least one occurs is just the sum of the individual probabilities. Each of those individual probabilities is a product of three probabilities, assuming that the three are colorblind in independent ways. For instance, the probability that Al is right is $0.9$, the probability that Bo is wrong is $1-0.8=0.2$, and the probability that Ci is wrong is $1-0.7=0.3$, so the probability of the first case above is $0.9\cdot0.2\cdot0.3$. Each of the other three cases is a similar product. Calculate them, add them up, and compare with the probability that Al by himself is wrong, and you’ll find that it’s very slightly better to send all three.